# How to add an ImageView outside and to the left of a Card?

Tags: android, imageview, android-cardview

This is what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

And this is what I have so far and the code below is the code for this screenshot

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Basically, I can't figure out how to get the image outside but still touching the card. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FrameLayout` and `elevation` to fulfill your target.

According to the documentation of FrameLayout

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child
>   on top

You need to play with the elevation of the `ImageView` to bring it above the `CardView`.

This is what I have achieved: You can then modify your paddings/margins according to design.

[image]

**Code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:layout_width="308dp"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:text="EARTH"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="70sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/planet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:elevation="2dp" />
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I changed one line in your code so it could work with my app which was I replaced android:src="@drawable/planet" with android:id="@+id/imageView" and when I run the app it now only displays one card! How would this work with lots of cards?

Comment: You can very well keep the android:id="@+id/imageView" to have a handle to the image view. My android:src="@drawable/planet" was just a static place holder drawable (the pink circle image) for the image view. These two are entirely different. You can programmatically set the drawable/image resource on the imageView later in your code. This layout is a child layout of your recyclerView. You have to have a adapter for populating your recyclerView with a number of items

Answer (score 1):

Try this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/first"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
            app:cardElevation="4dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TEXT"
                    android:textSize="18sp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image]